# Teams like software with multiple screen sharing simultaneously?

Tags: video-conferencing

Is there a Microsoft Teams like software that allows two people to share the screen simultaneously, has a chat and a video support, and works in Linux and Microsoft Windows?

Answer (score 0):

[Discord](https://discord.com/) might solve your needs.

It supports [multiple Videostreams](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045784891-Video-Screenshare-Updates-Multistream-and-More-),
has also a [Linux client](https://discord.com/download)
and you can add multiple chats or chanels.